# Сборка проекта через CMake выдает ошибку

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, mingw

прошу прощения, если вопрос уже был, но ничего путного по данному вопросу не нашел. Бился два дня подряд, так и не смог исправить. Вообщем. Создал папку test на рабочем столе. В ней три подпапки. build, include и src. В src поместил файл *.cpp, в include *.h. В папку test сохранил файл CMakeLists.txt.
Через консоль захожу в папку build, пытаюсь собрать проект, через команду cmake ../ и выдает кучу ошибок, не понимаю из-за чего. Вчера была немного другая ошибка. Он не видел идентификатор:

-The C compiler identification not find

-The CXX compiler identification not find

После я скачал Microsoft Visual Studio

С++ файлы собираю через MinGw. Там всё работает, а тут выдаёт вот это:

```
C:\Users\Станислав\Desktop\test\build>cmake ../
— The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.27.29112.0
— The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.27.29112.0
— Detecting C compiler ABI info
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: nmake /nologo cmTC_d2dbc\fast &&
— Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
— Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: nmake /nologo cmTC_f4fbf\fast &&
— Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/cmake-3.19.0-rc1-win64-x64/cmake-3.19.0-rc1-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:66 (message):
The C compiler

"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe"

is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: C:/Users/Станислав/Desktop/test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):nmake /nologo cmTC_f4fbf\fast && Не удается найти указанный файл
Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: nmake /nologo cmTC_f4fbf\fast &&




CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT)


— Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Станислав/Desktop/test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/Станислав/Desktop/test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: Читайте документацию. Создайте чистый проект на CMake (можно через Visual Studio или через Qt Creator, например) и посмотрите что сгенерируется. Начините хотя бы с этого.

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/

Comment: Всё, разобрался в чём была причина.